# How to detect extended trendline crossover in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

[image]

```
trendline = line.new(index, price, bar_index, close, xloc.bar_index, extend.right, color.red, line.style_solid, 1)

cross_up = barstate.ishistory and close > open and ta.crossover(close, line.get_y2(trendline))
```

I'm getting wrong results using line.get_y2() function. Seems it only returns Y2 price as it set in line.new() function. Is there a way to get crossover price at extended part of trendline?

Comment: Solved. I had to use line.get_price() instead of line.get_y2()